# XSLT 1.0 - Merge sibling nodes with child nodes into new composite nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I had a tough time formulating the question title. Maybe the example will make more sense.

Suppose I have an XML document that looks like this from system A:

```
<root>
    <phone_numbers>
        <phone_number type="work">123-WORK</phone_number>
        <phone_number type="home">456-HOME</phone_number>
        <phone_number type="work">789-WORK</phone_number>
        <phone_number type="other">012-OTHER</phone_number>
    </phone_numbers>
    <email_addresses>
        <email_address type="home">a@home</email_address>
        <email_address type="other">b@other</email_address>
        <email_address type="home">c@home</email_address>
        <email_address type="work">d@work</email_address>
        <email_address type="other">e@other</email_address>
        <email_address type="other">f@other</email_address>
    </email_addresses>
</root>
```

And I have to fit these into a structure like this so they can be used in system B:

```
<root>
    <addresses>
        <address name="work1">
            <phone_number>123-WORK</phone_number>
            <email_address>d@work</email_address>
        </address>
        <address name="work2">
            <phone_number>789-WORK</phone_number>
        </address>
        <address name="other1">
            <phone_number>012-OTHER</phone_number>
            <email_address>b@other</email_address>
        </address>
        <address name="other2">
            <email_address>e@other</email_address>
        </address>
        <address name="other3">
            <email_address>f@other</email_address>
        </address>
        <address name="home1">
            <phone_number>456-HOME</phone_number>
            <email_address>a@home</email_address>
        </address>
        <address name="home2">
            <email_address>c@home</email_address>
        </address>
    </addresses>
</root>
```

There can be any number (from 0 to infinity, as far as I know) of email addresses of each type. There can also be any number of phone numbers of each type, and the number of phone numbers of one type does not have to match the number of email addresses of the same type.

The email addresses and phone numbers in the first document aren't really related to each other, except that they are entered in the order they were added to system A.

I have to pair the emails and phone numbers up by type to fit into system B, and I would like to pair them so that the first phone number of type X is paired with the first email address of type X and so that no phone number of type X is paired with an email of a type other than X.

Since I have to pair them up, and since the order they were entered into the system is the closest I'll get to finding a relationship between the pairs, I would like to order them this way. I'll have to tell the users to go over the results, to make sure they make sense, but I have to pair them - no choice.

To complicate matters, my actual XML document has more nodes that I'll need to merge with phone_numbers and email_addresses, and I have more than two `@types`.

One other note: I'm already calculating the maximum number of nodes with any given `@type`, so with my example docs, I know that the maximum number of `<address>` nodes of a single `@type` is three (three `<email_address>` nodes with `@type=other` = three `<address>` nodes with `@name=otherX`).

Comment: Does the ordering of the types matter? The type `other` doesn't appear until the second `email_address` or the fourth `phone_number`, yet that type is second in your output.

Comment: Ordering of the types doesn't matter.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my solution for a considerably simpler solution :)

Comment: Also added a detailed explanation. Hope it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation is quite simpler** (only 3 templates and no modes):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kTypeByVal" match="@type" use="."/>

 <xsl:key name="kPhNumByType" match="phone_number"
  use="@type"/>

 <xsl:key name="kAddrByType" match="email_address"
  use="@type"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vallTypes" select=
 "/*/*/*/@type
          [generate-id()
          =
           generate-id(key('kTypeByVal',.)[1])
          ]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
   <addresses>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$vallTypes"/>
   </addresses>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@type">
  <xsl:variable name="vcurType" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="vPhoneNums" select="key('kPhNumByType',.)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vAddresses" select="key('kAddrByType',.)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vLonger" select=
  "$vPhoneNums[count($vPhoneNums) > count($vAddresses)]
  |
   $vAddresses[not(count($vPhoneNums) > count($vAddresses))]
  "/>

  <xsl:for-each select="$vLonger">
   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
   <address name="{$vcurType}{$vPos}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$vPhoneNums[position()=$vPos]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$vAddresses[position()=$vPos]"/>
   </address>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="phone_number|email_address">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (and any document with the described properties):

```
<root>
    <phone_numbers>
        <phone_number type="work">123-WORK</phone_number>
        <phone_number type="home">456-HOME</phone_number>
        <phone_number type="work">789-WORK</phone_number>
        <phone_number type="other">012-OTHER</phone_number>
    </phone_numbers>
    <email_addresses>
        <email_address type="home">a@home</email_address>
        <email_address type="other">b@other</email_address>
        <email_address type="home">c@home</email_address>
        <email_address type="work">d@work</email_address>
        <email_address type="other">e@other</email_address>
        <email_address type="other">f@other</email_address>
    </email_addresses>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <addresses>
      <address name="work1">
         <phone_number>123-WORK</phone_number>
         <email_address>d@work</email_address>
      </address>
      <address name="work2">
         <phone_number>789-WORK</phone_number>
      </address>
      <address name="home1">
         <phone_number>456-HOME</phone_number>
         <email_address>a@home</email_address>
      </address>
      <address name="home2">
         <email_address>c@home</email_address>
      </address>
      <address name="other1">
         <phone_number>012-OTHER</phone_number>
         <email_address>b@other</email_address>
      </address>
      <address name="other2">
         <email_address>e@other</email_address>
      </address>
      <address name="other3">
         <email_address>f@other</email_address>
      </address>
   </addresses>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **All different values of the `type` attribute are collected** in the `$vallTypes` variable, using the Muenchian method for grouping.
2. **For every distinct value found in 1. above, an `<address>` element is output** as follows.
3. **A `name` attribute is** generated with value the concatenation of the current `type` and the current `position()`.
4. **Two nodesets are captured in variables**: one containing all `phone_number` elements that has this specific value of their `type` attribute, and another containing all `email_address` elements that has this specific value of their `type` attribute.
5. **For every element of the longer of these two node-sets one element or (if possible a pair of elements from the two node-sets) is/are used to be generated** (omitting the `type` attribute`) in the final output.

Comment: This worked like a charm. As you can imagine, my example docs were extremely simplified, but I was able to modify your working stylesheet to transform the actual (substantially more complex) data.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="byType" match="/root/*/*" use="@type" />
    <xsl:key name="phoneByType" match="phone_numbers/phone_number"
        use="@type" />
    <xsl:key name="emailByType" match="email_addresses/email_address"
        use="@type" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <addresses>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </addresses>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/root/*/*" />
    <xsl:template
        match="/root/*/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('byType', @type)[1])]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('phoneByType', @type)"
            mode="wrap" />
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="key('emailByType', @type)
                [position() > count(key('phoneByType', @type))]"
            mode="wrap" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="phone_numbers/phone_number" mode="wrap">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
        <address name="{concat(@type, $pos)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="out" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('emailByType', @type)[$pos]"
                mode="out" />
        </address>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="email_addresses/email_address" mode="wrap">
        <address
            name="{concat(@type, 
                          position() + count(key('phoneByType', @type)))}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="out" />
        </address>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/root/*/*" mode="out">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On this input:

```
<root>
    <phone_numbers>
        <phone_number type="work">123-WORK</phone_number>
        <phone_number type="home">456-HOME</phone_number>
        <phone_number type="work">789-WORK</phone_number>
        <phone_number type="other">012-OTHER</phone_number>
    </phone_numbers>
    <email_addresses>
        <email_address type="home">a@home</email_address>
        <email_address type="other">b@other</email_address>
        <email_address type="home">c@home</email_address>
        <email_address type="work">d@work</email_address>
        <email_address type="other">e@other</email_address>
        <email_address type="other">f@other</email_address>
        <email_address type="test">g@other</email_address>
    </email_addresses>
</root>
```

Produces:

```
<root>
    <addresses>
        <address name="work1">
            <phone_number>123-WORK</phone_number>
            <email_address>d@work</email_address>
        </address>
        <address name="work2">
            <phone_number>789-WORK</phone_number>
        </address>
        <address name="home1">
            <phone_number>456-HOME</phone_number>
            <email_address>a@home</email_address>
        </address>
        <address name="home2">
            <email_address>c@home</email_address>
        </address>
        <address name="other1">
            <phone_number>012-OTHER</phone_number>
            <email_address>b@other</email_address>
        </address>
        <address name="other2">
            <email_address>e@other</email_address>
        </address>
        <address name="other3">
            <email_address>f@other</email_address>
        </address>
        <address name="test1">
            <email_address>g@other</email_address>
        </address>
    </addresses>
</root>
```

Explanation:

- There are three groups: 1) all contact info by type; 2) all phone numbers by type; 3) all email addresses by type
- The first group is used to get the first occurrence of each type
- Then we go through each of the phone numbers, pairing with any email address in the same position
- Finally, we account for all of the email addresses that did not have a corresponding phone number

Comment: That looks very promising. I'll take it for a spin this weekend and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: In case you drop by before then, I'd like to reiterate that I have more than two nodes (4, to be exact) and I have more than three types (4). I'm still trying to wrap my head around your stylesheet, so I'm not sure how much of a difference that'll make yet.

Comment: @tex - This will handle new `type` attributes without any changes -- notice that I added one called `test` to demonstrate this -- but it would require changes to support a new contact element (other than phone numbers and email addresses).

Comment: Thanks again for the help. If I could select two answers, I would, but I went with Dimitre's because it seemed a little clearer to me. +1 for you.